# VM returned with error err="gas uint64 overflow"

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js, quorum

I am running a private quorum network, and I am trying to call a contract function using web3;

my contract was deployed correctly, and i am able to see it and interact with it. Next is the code i am trying to run to add data to the my contract.

```
for (let i =51; i<500; i++){
  let jsonObj = Array[i];
  Cin.deployed().then(
    contractInstance=>{
      //console.log(web3.fromDecimal(i+2*i))
      contractInstance.insertPerson(
        web3.fromUtf8(web3.fromDecimal(i+2*i)),
        jsonObj["email"]?web3.fromUtf8(jsonObj["email"]):"",
        jsonObj["FIRST_NAME"]?web3.fromUtf8(jsonObj["FIRST_NAME"]):"",
        jsonObj["LAST_NAME"]?web3.fromUtf8(jsonObj["LAST_NAME"]):"",
       ...
          jsonObj["DECEASED_DT"]?web3.fromUtf8(jsonObj["DECEASED_DT"].toString()):""],
        {gas: 9900000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function(v) {
        fs.appendFileSync('./Pushed.txt',JSON.stringify(v)+"\n \n");
        pushedNumber++;
          console.log("pushed "+i +"   N: "+pushedNumber);


      }).catch(e=>{
        console.log("error in "+i);
        fs.appendFileSync('./log.txt',"Error form Inserting"+e+"\n \n");
      });
    }
  ).catch(e=>{
    fs.appendFileSync('./log.txt',"Deployment Error "+e+"\n \n");
  })

}
```

The problem here is when i call these functions i get this error on my geth console : 
`VM returned with error                   err="gas uint64 overflow"`

I can't understand why is that ? is it because i am sending too many transactions from a single account in small amount of time ?

**EDIT :**

this is the function that mostly does cause the error

```
function insertPerson(
    bytes32 personAddress,
    bytes32 email,
    bytes32 fname,
    bytes32 lname,
    Gender gender,
    string image,
    Status status,
    bytes32[13] details
)
    public
    returns(uint index)
  {
    if(isPerson(personAddress)) return;
    persons[personAddress].email = email;
    persons[personAddress].fname = fname;
    persons[personAddress].lname = lname;
    persons[personAddress].index = personIndex.push(personAddress)-1;
    persons[personAddress].deleted = false;
    persons[personAddress].gender = gender;
    persons[personAddress].image = image;
    persons[personAddress].status = status;
    persons[personAddress].RIM.Value = details[0];
    persons[personAddress].RIM.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
    persons[personAddress].RIM.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
    persons[personAddress].RIM.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].BirthCity.Value = details[1];
      persons[personAddress].BirthCity.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].BirthCity.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].BirthCity.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].BirthCountry.Value = details[2];
      persons[personAddress].BirthCountry.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].BirthCountry.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].BirthCountry.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].FatherName.Value = details[3];
      persons[personAddress].FatherName.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].FatherName.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].FatherName.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].MotherName.Value = details[4];
      persons[personAddress].MotherName.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].MotherName.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].MotherName.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].Citizenship.Value = details[5];
      persons[personAddress].Citizenship.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].Citizenship.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].Citizenship.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].Residency.Value = details[6];
      persons[personAddress].Residency.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].Residency.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].Residency.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].Grade.Value = details[7];
      persons[personAddress].Grade.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].Grade.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].Grade.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].CorpCountryCode.Value = details[8];
      persons[personAddress].CorpCountryCode.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].CorpCountryCode.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].CorpCountryCode.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].IntroducedBy.Value = details[9];
      persons[personAddress].IntroducedBy.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].IntroducedBy.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].IntroducedBy.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].HowIntroduced.Value = details[10];
      persons[personAddress].HowIntroduced.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].HowIntroduced.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].HowIntroduced.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].website.Value = details[11];
      persons[personAddress].website.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].website.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].website.status = Status.Validated;
    persons[personAddress].DeceasedDate.Value = details[12];
      persons[personAddress].DeceasedDate.ValidationDate = bytes32(now);
      persons[personAddress].DeceasedDate.ValidationDuration = bytes32(365);
      persons[personAddress].DeceasedDate.status = Status.Validated;
    //persons[personAddress].AttributesStatus["RIM"]= AttributeStatus('');
    return(uint(1));
  }
```

The most tthing bugging in this error is that the blockc gets mined and added to the blockchain but the data supposed to be stored doesn't get stored. so i don't get an error through web3 to tell my UI users to retry again. 
isn't VM error supposed to be errors that actually cancel the transaction ?

Answer (score 2):

You better look to the sources to find out which is your error case. Most likely your gas limit overflows a 64bit number , probably due to a bug in your contract.

here are some examples:

```
var errGasUintOverflow = errors.New("gas uint64 overflow")

func callGas(gasTable params.GasTable, availableGas, base uint64, callCost *big.Int) (uint64, error) {
    if gasTable.CreateBySuicide > 0 {
        availableGas = availableGas - base
        gas := availableGas - availableGas/64
        // If the bit length exceeds 64 bit we know that the newly calculated "gas" for EIP150
        // is smaller than the requested amount. Therefor we return the new gas instead
        // of returning an error.
        if callCost.BitLen() > 64 || gas < callCost.Uint64() {
            return gas, nil
        }
    }
    if callCost.BitLen() > 64 {
        return 0, errGasUintOverflow
    }

    return callCost.Uint64(), nil
}
============================ 
        var memorySize uint64
        // calculate the new memory size and expand the memory to fit
        // the operation
        if operation.memorySize != nil {
            memSize, overflow := bigUint64(operation.memorySize(stack))
            if overflow {
                return nil, errGasUintOverflow
            }
            // memory is expanded in words of 32 bytes. Gas
            // is also calculated in words.
            if memorySize, overflow = math.SafeMul(toWordSize(memSize), 32); overflow {
                return nil, errGasUintOverflow
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gas limit seems to be something hardcoded, how does my contract's bug overflow that limit

Comment: I think you should add the source of your contract to the question

Comment: I can't do that actually, but i can post the function that does usually cause this overflow, which i will do.